# CustomElements.js:596Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'customElements' of object '#<Window>'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-component, custom-element

We are leveraging skateJS and are using webcomponent.js for polyfills. However, since the new release of Google Chrome (Version 54.0.2840.71) today, our app is throwing a fatal error.

CustomElements.js:596Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'customElements' of object '#'

Comment: Maybe try asking Google support team, rather than SO?

Comment: This was a bug in the polyfill we were recommending the usage of. It's since been resolved. Sorry for the late reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 54, Chrome has introduced a new gobal variable named [`customElements`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#customelementregistry), actually `window.customElements`, which is part of the Custom Elements v1 specification.

It must be in conflict whith an identical variable that you use in your own code (guess in file *CustomElements.js*). You'll need to rename it.